# End subscription within subscribe callback

Tags: c#, websocket, system.reactive, reactive-programming

Code:

```
            subscription = source
                // close websocket eventually
                .Finally(() => webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.Empty, String.Empty, CancellationToken.None).Wait())
                .Subscribe(
                    data =>
                    {
                        if (webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning("Websocket closed by client!");
                            // TODO: End subscription
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            webSocket.SendAsync(data.ToString(),
                                WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
                        }
                        catch (WebSocketException e)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning(e, "problem with websocket!");
                            // TODO: End subscription
                        }
                    });
```

Explanation:

- Listening to events from "source"
- On data received -> send on websocket
- On exception or websocket closed => Should end subscription to "source" and make sure websocket is closed if it is not already. How??

One way to achieve that is by letting the exception go unhandled which will make the observer stop observing and call "finally", BUT the issue is that it then crashes my whole server since the exception is rethrown on some background thread and is unhandled.

Answer (score 0):

To end a subscription inside the callback you can just call `Dispose()` on the subscription:

```
 IDisposable subscription = null;

 ...


 subscription = source
                // close websocket eventually
                .Finally(() => webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.Empty, String.Empty, CancellationToken.None).Wait())
                .Subscribe(
                    data =>
                    {
                        if (webSocket.State != WebSocketState.Open)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning("Websocket closed by client!");
                            subscription.Dispose(); // End subscription
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            webSocket.SendAsync(data.ToString(),
                                WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None).Wait();
                        }
                        catch (WebSocketException e)
                        {
                            _logger.LogWarning(e, "problem with websocket!");
                            subscription.Dispose(); // End subscription
                        }
                    });
```

See also http://www.introtorx.com/content/v1.0.10621.0/03_LifetimeManagement.html#Unsubscribing

Comment: you can't access the subscription object in the callback, it hasn't been declared yet.

Comment: I did try I it out, before I posted it. As you can see in my answer I did declare the IDisposable subscription separately. Just don't use `var subscription = source ....`

Comment: @Spacemonkey if it is still not working can you show how and where you declare the subscription?

Comment: @Spacemonkey - It does work just fine when done in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You really should try to define your observable like this:

```
var subscription =
    source
        .TakeWhile(data => webSocket.State == WebSocketState.Open)
        .SelectMany(data =>
            Observable.FromAsync(() =>
                webSocket.SendAsync(data.ToString(), WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None)))
        .Catch<WebSocketException>(ex =>
            Observable.FromAsync(() =>
                webSocket.CloseAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.Empty, String.Empty, CancellationToken.None)))
        .Subscribe();
```

It'll end up automatically unsubscribing for you.

Even though you can, you should avoid unsubscribing in the observer.